# Java Event Generation

Tags: java

I want to design a system which will generate a specific event at a constant rate and this will continue doing in the background. In the foreground it give output of some other events if I want.
But the background event will not stop. What is the best way to achieve it in java?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newScheduledThreadPool%28int%29

Comment: You mean like a timer?

Comment: like parallel execution of two events. Can it be done without using threads?

Answer (score 2):

This is the definition of Threading and it needs to come with some level of understanding.

On a simplest level, make a Thread that sleeps for an amount of time then executes your code.  There are lots of other ways to do it, but few are shorter than just overriding the run method of a thread.

If you want something more abstract, look through the concurrent package in the Java docs, there are many methods that do exactly what you want, and java.util.timer is a good one to look at as well.

Be aware of variables and collections that might be accessed by different threads at the same time.  Also be aware if you have a GUI that you shuold not update your GUI from this new thread.

**Edit to add a Non-thread solution**

*(I don't think this is really what you want, but in the comments you asked for a non-threaded solution).*

If you wish to do this without threads (meaning you really wish to do it in your current thread) you have to occasionally "Interrupt" your current thread to check to see if your other task needs to process.  First you need a method like this:

```
long lastRun=System.currentTimeInMillis();
final long howOftenToRun=60*1000 // every minute

testForBackgroundTask() {
    if(lastRun + howOftenToRun < System.currentTimeInMillis()) {
        // This will drift, if you don't want drift use lastRun+=howOftenToRun
        lastRun=System.currentTimeInMillis() 
        // this is where your occasional task is.  
        // The task could be in-line here but of course that would violate the SRP            
        runBackgroundTask()         
    }
}
```

After that, you need to sprinkle testForBackgroundTask throughout your code:

```
lotsOfStuff....
testForBackgroundTask()
longMethod()
testForBackgroundTask()
morestuff...
testForBackgroundTask()
...
```

Note that if longMethod() takes a really long time then you will need to put calls to testForBackgroundTask() inside it as well.

I know this is ugly, and the uglyness of this solution is why threads are used.  The only advantage is that it will absolutely prevent threading conflicts.

The other single threaded solution--making your code event driven--is even harder and seriously impacts your code (There is a construct called a Finite State Engine made for this purpose).

Comment: As I said, what you want is the definition of thread but you CAN do it without threads but that brings its own set of problems--basically you make your whole program event driven, then your task is just another event, this is harder than threads (much) but safer because there are no concurrency issues

Comment: Look at Java.util.timer--it is a new thread but should be the easiest implementation. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_timer.htm